# System (awk) command saved as a variables error

Tags: r, variables, awk

I am having the following error:

```
a <- system("awk '{ if (/foo/) print "2","\t",$0; else print "1","\t",$0; }' file",intern=true)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "a \<- system("awk '{ if (/foo/) print "2"
```

I am wondering if I have to escape the internal apostrophe's but not sure how?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple errors in the code. The code below works for me and (per your comment) returns a two column data frame:

```r
a <- system("awk '{ if (/foo/) print 2 \"\t\" $0; else print 1 \"\t\" $0; }' file", intern = TRUE)
DF = read.table(text = a, sep = "\t")
DF
#>   V1  V2
#> 1  2 foo
#> 2  1 bar
#> 3  1 asd

summary(DF)
#>        V1             V2           
#>  Min.   :1.000   Length:3          
#>  1st Qu.:1.000   Class :character  
#>  Median :1.000   Mode  :character  
#>  Mean   :1.333                     
#>  3rd Qu.:1.500                     
#>  Max.   :2.000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I was able to run the command, however, the variable was not read as a data frame. I tried the following. `a <- data.frame(system("awk '{ if (/foo/) print 2 \t $0; else print 1 \t $0; }' file", intern = TRUE))` but the file is a character class and mode instead of dataframe. `summary(a)
   Length     Class      Mode 
   502506 character character`

Comment: @zerberus I modified the response, creating as an end result a two column data frame.

Comment: This is really helpful. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had an error with the seperator's and also wanted to keep the headers. I subsequently did the following, as I wanted to change the order.

```
file:
Header1 Header2
foo     bar
bar     bar
foo     foo
```

I then ran the command:

```
a <- system("awk '{ if (/foo/) print 2 \"\t\" $0; else print 1 \"\t\" $0; }' file | awk '{print $2,$3,$1}' ", intern = TRUE)
DF = read.table(text = a, sep = " ", header=TRUE)
colnames(DF)[3] <- "Header3"
```

Now the output:

```
DF
Header1 Header2 Header3
foo     bar     2
bar     bar     1
foo     foo     2
```

All works perfectly now. Thanks